# Enable Live metrics stream for Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm monitoring an on-prem IIS web app using Azure application insights, but when I check Live metrics stream, I can note that it does not work as shown in the following [image: figure]

As a result, I tried to install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights nugget using the following PowerShell Cmdlet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.7.1
```

But unfortunately, it does not work and I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Version'.
```

Considering that the version already exists and I've tried it with other versions.

Comment: If live metrics does not work installing Microsoft.ApplicationInsights won't help. LiveMetrics is part of PerfCounterCollector package.  Btw - can you re-paste the screenshot as nothing is seen here.

Comment: Done. Please, recheck the post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are behind a firewall or proxy.
Add the following to your .config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" autoDetect="True" proxyaddress="http://ip.address.of.your.proxy" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Please check you have an entry in ApplicationInsights.config for:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
```

in the `<TelemetryModules>` node.

and

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
```

in `<TelemetryProcessors>` node.

Comment: I have both in my `ApplicationInsights.config` but it still does not work.

Comment: Install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package in your application and you should be able to see the AppInsights in Live Metrics Stream

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package in your application and you should be able to see the AppInsights in Live Metrics Stream.